# Error: QOpenGLShader: could not create shader - while running through ssh

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, ssh

From my computer:

```
$ cat /etc/issue && uname -a
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l

Linux abc-pc 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**I am using Qt 5.4 and QtCreator 3.3.0**

I have read this answer regarding the [opengl errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20531527/462608), but I am not sure if that applies to me too.

The programs run very finely on my computer, but a peer does `ssh` from his own computer on my computer and runs the same program and the following errors are shown on his computer.

Doing `ssh` means that he is actually working on my computer so when I am not getting these errors why is he?

```
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Connected to  "xyz"
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( imageTexture ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
shader compilation failed: 
""
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( opacity ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
shader compilation failed: 
""
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( opacity ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( pixelSize ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
shader compilation failed:
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47062/what-is-terminal-command-that-can-show-opengl-version    This post on askubuntu provides a thorough discussion of this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try connecting with `ssh -X`, then running the command `DISPLAY=:0` after logging in, before starting the program.

I.e.

```
$ ssh -X YOURCOMP
...
$ DISPLAY=:0
$ ./[run gl program]
```

---

- [For a view as to what happens if you omit `-X`, and also setting `DISPLAY`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47062/what-is-terminal-command-that-can-show-opengl-version/294773#294773)
- [For an explanation of what `-X` does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566/how-does-ssh-x-function)
- [For an explanation of `DISPLAY=:0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746119/how-do-you-use-display-specifications)

All in all, it might let you access the remote machine's graphics drivers.
For instance, if you just ran
`glxinfo | grep OpenGL`, you will not get the expected result through `ssh`, unless you do both `ssh -X`, and `DISPLAY=:0` (as shown in the first link).

You can get `glxinfo` from `mesa-utils`.

---

Also, a nice GL program to test with is `glxgears` which is also from the `mesa-utils` package. If this works, and your program doesn't, it suggests that the problem might be because of something else.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But, kindly explain in your answer what does that do and why it is helpful.

Comment: Added a little explanation :)

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Did you get around to trying it?

Comment: Didn't work. Writing Display=0 opened the application on my own computer. Not what I want is this.